# Color Referencing a Related Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

New to coding. I am attempting to activate a color in a cell two rows below the current cell and am having difficulty making it work. Here is what I have so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function relatedCellColor() {


  var spreadSheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet     = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Data");
  var currentCell   = dataSheet.getCurrentCell();
  var relatedCell   = currentCell.offset(0,-2).getValue();

  var defColor      = dataSheet.getRange("DefaultColorCell").getBackgroundColor();

  relatedCell.setBackground(defColor);

}
```

Thank you all! This is the code that worked:

```
function relatedCellColor() {

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Data");

  var defColor = dataSheet.getRange("DefaultColorCell").getBackgroundColor();

  dataSheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2,0).setBackground(defColor);

}
```

Comment: This appears to be code using a specific API, SDK, or framework. Please [edit] your question and add the tag of the product you are coding against, so that people who are experts in that product can help you.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks! I just added a tag. I am coding in Google Apps Script.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow!! [how-to-ask-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with only the code of this function it is not easy to help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function relatedCellColor() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  sh.getCurrentCell().offset(2,0).setBackground("DefaultColorCell");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get it to work using your variation, though this did work! I appreciate the guidance!

```function relatedCellColor() {

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Data");

  ```var defColor      = dataSheet.getRange("DefaultColorCell").getBackgroundColor();

  dataSheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2,0).setBackground(defColor);

}```

Comment: I was thinking that DefaultColorCell was just a color.